# Help a Python newbie with a Django model inheritance problem

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-inheritance

I'm working on my first real Django project after years of PHP programming, and I am running into a problem with my models.  First, I noticed that I was copying and pasting code between the models, and being a diligent OO programmer I decided to make a parent class that the other models could inherit from:

```
class Common(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        abstract=True
```

So far so good.  Now all my other models extend "Common" and have names and dates like I want.  However, I have a class for "Categories" were the name has to be unique.  I assume there should be a relatively simple way for me to access the name attribute from Common and make it unique.  However, the different methods I have tried to use have all failed.  For example:

```
class Category(Common):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name.unique=True
```

Causes the Django admin page to spit up the error "Caught an exception while rendering: 'Category' object has no attribute 'name'

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Django doesn't allow that.

See the docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted

Also answered in other questions like: [In Django - Model Inheritance - Does it allow you to override a parent model's attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344751/in-django-model-inheritance-does-it-allow-you-to-override-a-parent-models-at)

Comment: I'm a little shocked to see that in the docs... that seems like a pretty big omission!

Comment: Well, model inheritance was missing entirely from Django for quite some time, so I think this is a big improvement. I'm not entirely sure, but I think you might be able to implement your unique=true in a custom manager. Or, you might be able to use multiple inheritance and have the UNIQUE_NAME as a mixin.

Answer (score 1):

You have a small mistake in your `Common` class

```
class Common(model.Model):
    self.name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

should be

```
class Common(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: think that must be a copy-and-paste issue, since it's not valid Python - self isn't defined at that point.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion over the typo.  Since I am new to Python I've been experimenting with lots of odd code just to see what happens, and that was one of my experiments which I meant to clean up before pasting into Stackoverflow.

Unfortunately, my code doesn't work even with the typo removed

Answer (score 1):

Note that UNIQUE constraint in fact has nothing to do with Django, so you're free to add it in your database table. You can also use [post-syncdb](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-syncdb) hook for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Meta.unique_together` to force it into its own unique index. Failing that, it's probably easiest to create two separate abstract classes, one with the field unique and one not.