# How can i change the field type in django models by overriding the class

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-oscar

I have one class in core folder as below:

```
class AbstractLine(models.Model):
    basket = models.ForeignKey('basket.Basket', related_name='lines',
                           verbose_name=_("Basket"))

    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Quantity'), default=1)
```

Now I want to override this class in order to change the quantity `PositiveIntegerField` to `DecimalField` as below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from oscar.apps.basket.abstract_models import AbstractLine as ModelLine

class Line(ModelLine):
    quantity = models.DecimalField(_('Quantity'), default=0.25, decimal_places=2, max_digits=3)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is AbstractLine actually an abstract class?

Comment: Yes. it is abstract class.

Comment: what is wrong with the way you have it written?

Comment: This way is not working #Burhan Khalid

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's not possible. See this question: [In Django - Model Inheritance - Does it allow you to override a parent model's attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344751/in-django-model-inheritance-does-it-allow-you-to-override-a-parent-models-a)

The same applies to abstract base classes also, see [this discussion on the Django user's group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/ToHk3tlkf0k).

Your best bet is to simply delete the field from the base class.