# Model subclass: override CharField max_length

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a supplied database schema for which I want to create a Django application. Many of the tables in the schema share a common set of columns, such as `name` and `date_created`. That prompted me to create an abstract `Standard_model` class containing those columns, and subclass the relevant models from it.

Unfortunately, some of the tables have a `name` column with a different `max_length`. I'm trying to come up with a way for the subclassed model to pass the `max_length` value to the abstract base class, but I'm drawing a blank.

Any ideas?

```
class Standard_model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyModel(Standard_model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)  # Can't do this.
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you [cannot override the `name` field definition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted):

> In normal Python class inheritance, it is permissible for a child
>   class to override any attribute from the parent class. In Django, this
>   is not permitted for attributes that are Field instances (at least,
>   not at the moment). If a base class has a field called author, you
>   cannot create another model field called author in any class that
>   inherits from that base class.

See also:

- [In Django - Model Inheritance - Does it allow you to override a parent model's attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344751/in-django-model-inheritance-does-it-allow-you-to-override-a-parent-models-a)

And, FYI, according to the [model naming convention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style), it should be called `StandardModel`.

Comment: I already have - sorry, I thought that was clear. I'll edit the code sample to make it clearer.

Comment: I was curious about this too. I didn't think it was possible and now I know for sure after your edit. But in the example above, not like it matters. Just make both length 80.

Comment: @dan-klasson yup, but the problem is that there can be multiple models with different `max_length` value of the `name ` field. The solution would be to remove it from the `StandardModel` and define in every single class there it is needed.

Comment: Yeah or just make all the fields for the different models what the maximum field is. Not like it matters much unless you have millions of rows.