# Django override-able abstract field for inlineformset

Tags: django, forms, inheritance, model

**Intro**

Hello!!!!! I've looked for the solution to this problem already - the nearest thing I've found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344751/in-django-model-inheritance-does-it-allow-you-to-override-a-parent-models-a), and it doesn't have a full enough answer for me.

**Background**

The following is a contrived example to make my question clearer.

I am interested in using `inlineformset_factory` in a situation where each entry in the form can correspond to different subclasses of the same parent model. For example, say I have a form model that has a number of input items:

```
class Form(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Then, I have an `Input` model and its subclasses:

```
class Input(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    form = models.ForeignKey(Form)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ShortInput(Input):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class TweetInput(Input):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=140)

class BinaryInput(Input):
    value = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Essentially, it's a form with various types of data. It's important that `ShortInput` instances only take up 20 characters of space in the backend, and `BinaryInput` instances have a huge amount of storage space. Note also that every subclass of `Input` will always have a `value` field, although they may be of different lengths/types.

What I'd like to do now is use `inlineformset_factory` to build the `Form` model. Looks like this:

```
form = inlineformset_factory(
    Form,
    Input,
    fk_name='form',
    fields=['value']
)
```

The intention here is to build a form where I can edit the values of every `Input` entry in the database.

**The problem**

For the `inlineformset_factory` call, Django complains that `Input` has no field named `value`.

**The question**

I feel I should be able to deal with this problem because I can guarantee every `Input` subclass *will* have a `value` attribute - I just need to tell this to Django in some way. The ideal thing I'm looking for is something like this:

```
class Input(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        guaranteed_subclass_fields = [
            'value',
        ]
    ...
```

In other words, a way of telling Django it can expect a `value` field in subclasses.

The next best thing I'm looking for is some other way of specifying to Django that it can rely on a `value` field existing.

Finally, if none of this is possible, I'm looking for some other (potentially hackish) way of passing my `Input` class with a `value` field to the `inlineformset_factory` function - perhaps ignoring the error or something of the sort. (Although regardless of how hackish the solution is, I would like it to involve the use of `inlineformset_factory`)

Thanks in advance for any help!