# Python - Inherit from class which inherit Model

Tags: python, django, inheritance

Here is my problem: I try to create layer under

```
models.Model
```

My Model -

```
class MainModel(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def getIf(condition):
        results = __class__.objects.filter(condition)
        if results.count() > 0:
            return results.first()
        else:
            return None
```

And that's a model

```
class User(MainModel):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

But my project is crushed with error -

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'id' in class 'User'
>   clashes with field of the same name from base class 'MainModel'.

What am I doing wrong?

UPD: if you want to do like this, you need to use subclass Meta in your layer

```
class MainModel(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def getIf(condition:dict):
        results = __class__.objects.filter(condition)
        if results.count() > 0:
            return results.first()
        else:
            return None

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [model inheritence](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)?

Comment: Use `user_id` in place of `id`.

Comment: not, of course, if I asks )) ok, I found what I lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanx, but I'm not trying to override fields, In my layer no one field is not defined. I found my answer, I just have to read documentation.

if you want to do like this, you need to use subclass Meta in your layer

```
class MainModel(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def getIf(condition:dict):
        results = __class__.objects.filter(condition)
        if results.count() > 0:
            return results.first()
        else:
            return None

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could make MainModel a mixin, that inherits from just `object`, and then your actual model can be `class User(MainModel, models.Model)`.

Comment: yee, thanks :) it was one of my trying, but I want to understand as much as I can and had to understand how can I do exactly it )

Answer (score 1):

Django adds a field `id` to all Models, you have to remove it.

Ok I understand your question better now, your answer is there:

[In Django - Model Inheritance - Does it allow you to override a parent model's attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344751/in-django-model-inheritance-does-it-allow-you-to-override-a-parent-models-a)

Django already adds a field id to your parent model.

Comment: But if I create it directly in class, which inherit models.Model all is fine - field id successfully created in db