# Django - override base class model field on get

Tags: python, django, orm, django-1.6

I am using Django1.6

i have abstract class A, and class B:

```
class A(Model):
    att = CharField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class B(A):
    pass
```

i want to override the behaviour of 'att' (without touching class A):
so when using:

```
b = B(att='a').save()
b.att  (output is 'a')
```

but i want to override the output:
so:

`b.att`  (output is something else like 'a_thanks')

```
class B(A):
    @propert
    def att(self):
        return self._att + '_thanks'
```

how can i do it?
i know this is [possible from django 1.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344751/in-django-model-inheritance-does-it-allow-you-to-override-a-parent-models-a)

Comment: question is updated

Comment: is there a problem with the answer you linked to?...oh, maybe you are telling you don't want to make class A abstract...

Comment: You could try creating a `class AAbstract(A)` with meta `abstract=True`, don't know if it might work.

Comment: @progmatico i cant do any changes to class A

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil i updated the question. maybe now its more clear