# Wagtail: change max_length of Page.title

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, wagtail

I'm working on a website for a public administration. In this website some pages might have a title which is longer than 255 characters.

**Is it possible to change the default max_length of the Page title?**

Thanks for the help

I'm using:

- Python 2.7;
- Django 1.11;
- Wagtail 1.13.4;

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking to do, in regards of django, is basically overriding parent model's attribute. There is answer about that here: [In Django - Model Inheritance - Does it allow you to override a parent model's attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344751/in-django-model-inheritance-does-it-allow-you-to-override-a-parent-models-a).

So, the answer is that no, you can't do it like that without some serious hacking. Maybe you should consider adding different property that you could use when rendering the page. It could, by default, use the title or something like that.