# Django: Override inherited field options

Tags: python, django, oop, inheritance, django-models

I am working with Django 3.2 and I would like to create an abstract class with 2 fields whose default values (or their blank attribute) could change in each of the child classes.

**I'd like not to override the full fields but only the options that change**. That way, if  I decide to make the icon field unique in the future, I should only change the parent abstract class and not all the child models.

```py
# behaviors.py

from django.db import models
from colorfield.fields import ColorField


class Representable(models.Model):
    color = ColorField(_("color in the app"), blank=True)
    icon = models.CharField(_("icon in the app"), max_length=50, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models
from .behaviors import Representable


class Item(Representable, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=50, blank=False)
    # color couldn't be blank
    # icon couldn't be blank    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("item")
        verbose_name_plural = _("items")


class Tag(Representable, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=200, blank=False, unique=True)
    # color default value shoud be #00AEC7 (but could be blank)
    # icon default value shoud be mdi-label (but could be blank)    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("tag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("tags")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57070366/3333028

But this solution monkey-patches the field and keep the changes made across the entire app.

Answer (score 1):

You can override fields in subclasses of abstract models and set whatever attributes you want

```
class Tag(Representable):
    ...
    color = ColorField(_("color in the app"), blank=True, default='#00AEC7')
    icon = models.CharField(_("icon in the app"), max_length=50, blank=True, default='mdi-label')
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I forgot to clarify that I know the standard way to do it. What I'm looking for is to reuse as much code as possible. Imagine that in a few months I decide that the icon must be unique. I wouldn't like to edit all the fields in all the child models.

Comment: I've seen solutions like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57070366/3333028

I can't monkey patch the field, since there will be many child models with different configurations.

Comment: Your wish is to be able to override attributes of inherited fields without re-defining them?

Comment: Exactly. I'd love to keep my code as DRY as possible.  I'd like to re-define only those options that change, not the full field.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert but this can work:

```
from django.db import models
from .behaviors import Representable


class Item(Representable):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
    color = ColorField(_("color in the app"), blank=False)
    icon = models.CharField(_("icon in the app"), max_length=50, blank=False)   

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("item")
        verbose_name_plural = _("items")


class Tag(Representable):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=200, blank=False, unique=True)
    color = ColorField(_("color in the app"), blank=True,null=True, default='#00AEC7')
    icon = models.CharField(_("icon in the app"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default='mdi-label')   

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("tag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("tags")
```

Comment: You're right, that's the standard way to do it. But, I'm trying not to override the full field, only the options that change. Sorry, I forgot to mention that in the question :(

Answer (score 0):

The below code achieves what you want, and works in my own cursory testing, but I'm unsure whether it's advisable to `deepcopy()` a field:

```py
# models.py

from copy import deepcopy
from django.db import models
from .behaviors import Representable

ColorRequiredField = deepcopy(Representable._meta.get_field('color'))
ColorRequiredField.blank = False
IconRequiredField = deepcopy(Representable._meta.get_field('icon'))
IconRequiredField.blank = False


class Item(Representable, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=50, blank=False)
    # color couldn't be blank
    color = ColorRequiredField
    # icon couldn't be blank    
    icon = IconRequiredField


TagColorField = deepcopy(Representable._meta.get_field('color'))
TagColorField.default = '#00AEC7'
TagIconField = deepcopy(Representable._meta.get_field('icon'))
TagIconField.default = 'mdi-label'

class Tag(Representable, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=200, blank=False, unique=True)
    # color default value shoud be #00AEC7 (but could be blank)
    color = TagColorField
    # icon default value shoud be mdi-label (but could be blank)
    icon = TagIconField
```